# How to create and start working with a graph database in Titan/Rexster from Bulbs

Tags: cassandra, titan, tinkerpop, bulbs, rexster

I've downloaded `titan-server-0.4.4.zip` and unzipped it and ran :

```
$ bin/titan.sh start
```

This started both `Cassandra` and `Titan + Rexster`. Now, I want to create a new graph for my application (say 'ggg') that I want to create from Bulbs in my Python source code. This is what I tried in the python2.7 console :

```
>>> from bulbs.titan import Graph, Config
>>> config = Config('/home/kevin/ggg') 
>>> g = Graph(config)     # Hoping that this will create all the graph related files
```

Now, I went to the rexster web interface and I could see only one graph named `graph`

```
{"version":"2.4.0","name":"Rexster: A Graph Server","graphs":["graph"],
"queryTime":0.567623,"upTime":"0[d]:05[h]:43[m]:05[s]"}
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong or missing? I tried looking at the documentation but couldn't find anything that helped me with this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @espeed Both the answers helped. Is there a way to merge the answers or should I just accept any one answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to edit rexster's config file to inform it about the new graph.
this is my config/rexster.xml entry

```
<graph-name>productionDB</graph-name>
  <graphtype>com.thinkaurelius.titan.tinkerpop.rexster.TitanGraphConfiguration</graphtype>
  <graph-location>/db/titan/main</graph-location>
  <graph-read-only>false</graph-read-only>
  <properties>
        <storage.backend>cassandra</storage.backend>
        <storage.hostname>127.0.0.1</storage.hostname>
        <storage.buffer-size>100</storage.buffer-size>
  </properties>
  <extensions>
    <allows>
      <allow>tp:gremlin</allow>
    </allows>
  </extensions>
</graph>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whereas Rexster supports multiple graphs on one server, Titan Server only supports one graph, and by default it's named "graph":

The `bulbs.titan module` is preconfigured to use `graph` as the name so to keep things simple, don't change the name in your Titan config, and thus you can then use the default Bulbs config without modifying it:

```
>>> from bulbs.titan import Graph
>>> g = Graph()   # using default config
```

See https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/blob/master/bulbs/titan/client.py#L29

BTW: If you were to use a different graph name, you'll need to supply its Titan Server URI, not the file path.

In other words, don't do this:

```
>>> config = Config('/home/kevin/ggg')
```

...do this...

```
>>> config = Config('http://localhost:8182/graphs/ggg')
```